# Change + key function to tab with only one stroke

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I would like to have the + key on the right hand keypad function as the tab key.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) is what you are after. It's able to remap the keys on your keyboard to perform other functions, such as changing the <kbd>+</kbd> to a <kbd>tab</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  That would be a fairly simple script:

> NumpadAdd::Tab